# What is this task type?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, assignment-problem

There are people and the food they prefer:
John -20> Apple
John -10> Pear
Ethan -20> Apple
Ethan -5> Orange
Michael -10> Pear
Michael -10> Limon

The numbers indicate how strongly they prefer the respective food.
i.e. *John likes Apple more than Pear* (20 > 10). And so for everyone.

The task is to distribute food to absolutely all people, trying to give the most preferred food as much as possible.

Expected result:
John -10> Pear
Ethan -20> Apple
Michael -10> Limon
S = 10 + 20 + 10 = 40

But if so:
John -20> Apple
Ethan -5> Orange
Michael -10> Pear
S = 20 + 5 + 10 = 35 (<40 — not expected result)

With different initial data, there may be several solutions with the same maximum S.
These solutions must be kept without discarding.

**(1) What kind of task is this and (2) What algorithm should be applied?**

Comment: Take a look at the following and see what you find: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_flow_problem

Comment: @d-w thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Assignment problem.**
**2. Hungarian algorithm.**

Python code:

```python
# pip install munkres

from typing import Dict, Union

from munkres import Munkres

G = {
    'John': {'Apple': 20, 'Pear': 10},
    'Ethan': {'Apple': 20, 'Orange': 5},
    'Michael': {'Pear': 10, 'Limon': 10},
}


def find_matching(graph: Dict[str, Dict[str, Union[int, float]]],
                  matching_type=Union['max', 'min'],
                  return_type=Union['list', 'int', 'float', 'number'],
                  big_number: int = 1_000_000):
    negate = -1 if matching_type == 'min' else +1
    items_d, rows_d, cols_d = dict(), dict(), dict()
    n, m = 0, 0
    for row_name, cols in graph.items():
        if row_name not in rows_d:
            rows_d[n] = row_name
            rows_d[row_name] = n
            n += 1
        for item_name, cost in cols.items():
            if item_name not in cols_d:
                cols_d[m] = item_name
                cols_d[item_name] = m
                m += 1
            items_d[(rows_d[row_name], cols_d[item_name])] = cost * negate
    matrix = [[items_d[(i, j)] if (i, j) in items_d else big_number for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]
    indexes = Munkres().compute(matrix)
    r_list = []
    r_number = 0
    for i, j in indexes:
        cost = matrix[i][j] * negate
        r_list.append(((rows_d[i], cols_d[j]), cost))
        r_number += cost
    if return_type == 'int':
        return int(r_number)
    if return_type == 'float':
        return float(r_number)
    if return_type == 'number':
        return r_number
    return r_list


print(find_matching(graph=G, matching_type='max', return_type='number'))
print(find_matching(graph=G, matching_type='max', return_type='list'))
```